# Dynamic dropdown list in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to generate State - District dropdown multi select dropdowns in Wordpress.. According to the selections of States, Districts has to be loaded..

Please suggest me if there is available any plugin..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently written a blog post about this: http://bdwm.be/how-to-create-dynamically-populated-cascading-dropdown-lists-for-contact-form-7/. This example is with cars, but I applied to your case it would look something like this:

You could start with a CSV file containing all the states/districts, like this:

```
State,District
Alabama,"District 1"
Alabame,"District 2"
....
```

save it as states_districts.csv and place it somewhere on your server. (In this example I placed it in the wp-content/uploads folder)

Then using the contact form 7 plugin create 2 select fields:

```
[select states]
[select districts]
```

Next, create some javascript in your page's footer, that will perform an AJAX call

```
<script>
(function($) {

    // create references to the dropdown fields for later use.

    var $states_dd = $('[name="states"]');
    var $districts_dd = $('[name="districts"]'); 

    // run the populate_fields function, and additionally run it every time a value changes

    populate_fields();
    $('select').change(function() {
        populate_fields();
    });

    function populate_fields() {

        var data = {

            // action needs to match the action hook part after wp_ajax_nopriv_ and wp_ajax_ in the server side script.

            'action' : 'cf7_populate_values', 

            // pass all the currently selected values to the server side script.

            'state' : $states_dd.val(),
            'district' : $districts_dd.val(),
        };

        // call the server side script, and on completion, update all dropdown lists with the received values.

        $.post('<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>', data, function(response) {
            all_values = response;

            $states_dd.html('').append($('<option>').text(' -- choose state -- '));
            $districts_dd.html('').append($('<option>').text(' -- choose district  -- '));

            $.each(all_values.states, function() {
                $option = $("<option>").text(this).val(this);
                if (all_values.current_state == this) {
                    $option.attr('selected','selected');
                }
                $states_dd.append($option);
            });
            $.each(all_values.districts, function() {
                $option = $("<option>").text(this).val(this);
                if (all_values.current_district == this) {
                    $option.attr('selected','selected');
                }
                $districts_dd.append($option);
            });
        },'json');
    }

})( jQuery );
</script>
```

Finish up by creating your server side function that will read in the CSV file and return the correct values to the javascript:

add this to functions.php:

```
function ajax_cf7_populate_values() {

    // read the CSV file in the $states_districts array

    $states_districts = array();
    $uploads_folder = wp_upload_dir()['basedir'];
    $file = fopen($uploads_folder.'\states_districts.csv', 'r');

    $firstline = true;
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
        if ($firstline) {
            $firstline = false;
            continue;
        }
        $states_districts[$line[0]][$line[1]][] = $line[2];

    }
    fclose($file);

        // setup the initial array that will be returned to the the client side script as a JSON object.

    $return_array = array(
            'states' => array_keys($states_districts),
            'districts' => array(),
            'current_state' => false,
            'current_district' => false
        );

        // collect the posted values from the submitted form

    $state= key_exists('state', $_POST) ? $_POST['state'] : false;
    $district = key_exists('district', $_POST) ? $_POST['district'] : false;

        // populate the $return_array with the necessary values

    if ($state) {
        $return_array['current_state'] = $state;
        $return_array['districts'] = array_keys($states_districts[$state]);
        if ($district) {
            $return_array['current_district'] = $district;
        }

        // encode the $return_array as a JSON object and echo it

        echo json_encode($return_array);
        wp_die();

}

// These action hooks are needed to tell WordPress that the cf7_populate_values() function needs to be called
// if a script is POSTing the action : 'cf7_populate_values'

add_action( 'wp_ajax_cf7_populate_values', 'ajax_cf7_populate_values' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_cf7_populate_values', 'ajax_cf7_populate_values' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to share a fix for anyone that is trying to use this code.
There is a mistake in line:

```
$file = fopen($uploads_folder.'\states_districts.csv', 'r');
```

it should be

```
$file = fopen($uploads_folder.'/states_districts.csv', 'r');
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you wish to use the drop downs ? In plugins or in themes or just in page ?

This can be done using Ajax calls. In general, you should register a Ajax call handler in plugin/theme and add your dynamic dropdowns in your page.

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

jQuery is embedded with Wordpress, check this section on how to create dynamic dropdown

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Dynamic-jQuery-Cascading-Dropdown-Lists-Plugin/